# SQL Query question

Tags: database, join, left-join

No particular DBMS in mind, how would I do the following:

```
# There are many tables per one restaurant, many napkins per one table
# Pseudo SQL

SELECT RESTAURANT WHERE ID = X;
SELECT ALL TABLES WHERE RESTAURANT_ID = RESTAURANT.ID;
SELECT ALL NAPKINS WHERE TABLE_ID = TABLE.ID;
```

But, all in one query? I've used a JOIN to get all the tables in the same query as restaurant, but is it possible to get all napkins for each table as well, in the same query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * -- replace * with the columns you need...
from restaurant as r 
    inner join tables as t on t.restaurant_id = r.id
    inner join napkins as n on n.table_id = t.id
where r.id = [restaurant id]
```

Comment: @John - I would need all the columns in `restaurant`, but only one time, you know what I mean. If the query returns a copy of restaurant for each other object it return, that should qualify as a pessimization, no?

Comment: @orokusaki that sounds like a presentation concern, which should be dealt with by the app consuming this data.  Not really a SQL issue...

Answer (score 0):

You would definitely end up in repeating Tables and restaurant information on the rows, like:

*Restaurant1* **Table1** Napkin1
*Restaurant1* **Table1** Napkin2
*Restaurant1* **Table1** Napkin3
*Restaurant1* Table2 Napkin4
Restaurant2 Table1 Napkin5

Comment: @user490881 - so there is no way to get one copy of restaurant, one copy of each table, and one copy of each napkin in one query? What about a left join?

Comment: @orokusaki -- you are not really "getting" multiple copies of Table1 etc. You are being presented with a single row at a time with all the values you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to return three separate results, not a single result with repeat values for RESTAURANT_N or TABLE_N.

In SQL, this is done with stored procedures which can return multiple result sets. The syntax for stored procedures varies among database products, therefore you should ask the question for specific products. In the stored procedure, there will be three select statements for the RESTAURANTS, TABLES and NAPKINS. The results of the three statements are returned in a bundle to the application, which can then use the results.